# How to randomly generate continuous functions

Tags: python, random, interpolation, curve-fitting, curve

My objective is to randomly generate good looking continuous functions, good looking meaning that functions which can be recovered from their plots.

Essentially I want to generate a random time series data for 1 second with 1024 samples per second. If I randomly choose 1024 values, then the plot looks very noisy and nothing meaningful can be extracted out of it. In the end I have attached plots of two sinusoids, one with a frequency of 3Hz and another with a frequency of 100Hz. I consider 3Hz cosine as a good function because I can extract back the timeseries by looking at the plot. But the 100 Hz sinusoid is bad for me as I cant recover the timeseries from the plot. So in the above mentioned meaning of goodness of a timeseries, I want to randomly generate good looking continuos functions/timeseries.

The method I am thinking of using is as follows (python language):

(1) Choose 32 points in x-axis between 0 to 1 using  `x=linspace(0,1,32)`.

(2) For each of these 32 points choose a random value using `y=np.random.rand(32)`.

(3) Then I need an interpolation or curve fitting method which takes as input (x,y) and outputs a continuos function which would look something like `func=curve_fit(x,y)`

(4) I can obtain the time seires by sampling from the func function

Following are the questions that I have:

> 1) What is the best curve-fitting or interpolation method that I can
>   use. They should also be available in python.
>
> 2) Is there a better method to generate good looking functions,
>   without using curve fitting or interpolation.

[image: A Cosine wave with frequency of 3Hz]

[image: A Cosine wave with frequency of 100Hz]

**Edit**

Here is the code I am using currently for generating random time-series of length 1024. In my case I need to scale the function between 0 and 1 in the y-axis. Hence for me l=0 and h=0. If that scaling is not needed you just need to uncomment a line in each function to randomize the scaling.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Curve fitting technique
def random_poly_fit():
    l=0
    h=1
    degree = np.random.randint(2,11)
    c_points = np.random.randint(2,32)
    cx = np.linspace(0,1,c_points)
    cy = np.random.rand(c_points)
    z = np.polyfit(cx, cy, degree)
    f = np.poly1d(z)
    y = f(x)
    # l,h=np.sort(np.random.rand(2))
    y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(l,h)).fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
    return y

## Cubic Spline Interpolation technique
def random_cubic_spline():
    l=0
    h=1
    c_points = np.random.randint(4,32)
    cx = np.linspace(0,1,c_points)
    cy = np.random.rand(c_points)
    z = interpolate.CubicSpline(cx, cy)
    y = z(x)
    # l,h=np.sort(np.random.rand(2))
    y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(l,h)).fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
    return y

func_families = [random_poly_fit, random_cubic_spline]
func = np.random.choice(func_families)
x = np.linspace(0,1,1024)
y = func()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You don't want that type of randomness in your function that makes it non-fitable ( at least the is no easy access closed form via fitting). You want a random combination of functions that can be fitted. I'm asking because that is quite a difference.

Comment: Usually people generate smooth curve with added gaussian (white) noise, along the lines `v(t)=f(t) + eps*N(0,1)`, https://machinelearningmastery.com/white-noise-time-series-python/

Comment: Would fitting random data to a smoothing spline work for your purpose?

Comment: Thats what I am currently doing. I'll edit the question and post the code I am using

Answer (score 2):

Add `sin` and `cosine` signals

```
from numpy.random import randint
x= np.linspace(0,1,1000)
for i in range(10):    
    y = randint(0,100)*np.sin(randint(0,100)*x)+randint(0,100)*np.cos(randint(0,100)*x)
    y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

convolve `sin` and `cosine` signals

```
for i in range(10):    
    y = np.convolve(randint(0,100)*np.sin(randint(0,100)*x), randint(0,100)*np.cos(randint(0,100)*x), 'same')
    y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to sampling from a Gaussian Process model (i.e., using Gaussian Process simulation via the spectral method, see [Cressie, 1993, Statistics for Spatial Data]), which I think is a pretty good solution to this question.